# Llenar campos input text ,date, select, a partir de un select option cargado desde la base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, ajax

Tengo un problema como podría rellenar mis `input text`, `input date` y otro `select option`  una vez que yo seleccione una opción de mi `select` y extrayendo los datos de la base de datos.se pudiera usar el evento `onchange`.

les dejo mi código del formulario:

```
<select  name="no_unidad" id="no_unidad" class="form-control" onchange="mifuncion(this.value)">
  <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
    <?php
      // Realizamos la consulta para extraer los datos
      $query="SELECT  * FROM vehiculo";
      $result=mysqli_query($con, $query) or die (mysqli_error());
      while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
      // En esta sección estamos llenando el select con datos extraidos de una base de datos.
      echo '<option value="'.$row['no_unidad'].'">'.$row['vehiculo'].'</option>';
    }
  ?>
</select>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="rendimiento" id="rendimiento" placeholder="Rendimiento"> 
<input type="date" class="form-control" name="fecha" id="fecha"> 

<select name="empresa" id="empresa" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
  <option value="csn">CSN</option>
  <option value="sea">SEA</option>
  <option value="cta">CTA</option>      
</select>  


    function mifuncion(valor){
    $.ajax({     
      url : 'scripts/cargar_valores.php',     
      data : { valor : valor },
      type : 'POST',
      dataType : 'json',
      success : function(json) {
        $("#rendimiento").val(json.rendimiento);
        $("#status").val(json.status);
        $("#fecha").val(json.fecha);
        $("#empresa").val(json.empresa);
        $("#departamento").val(json.departamento);
      },
        error : function(xhr, status) {
        alert('Disculpe, existió un problema');
      }
   });
  }
```

pagina cargar_valores.php donde hago la consulta:

```
 <?php
     $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","controldeflotilla") or die (mysqli_error());

    $valor=$_POST['valor'];

    $jsondata = array();

    $query="SELECT rendimiento,status,fecha,empresa,departamento from vehiculo where no_unidad=$valor";
    $r=mysql_query($query);
    $resultados= mysqli_fetch_array($r);

    $rendimiento=$resultados['rendimiento'];
    $status=$resultados['status'];
    $fecha=$resultados['fecha'];
    $empresa=$resultados['empresa'];
    $departamento=$resultados['departamento'];


    $jsondata['rendimiento'] = $rendimiento;
    $jsondata['status'] = $status;
    $jsondata['fecha'] = $fecha;
    $jsondata['empresa'] = $empresa;
    $jsondata['departamento'] = $departamento;


     header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
     echo json_encode($jsondata); 
     mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Usando AJAX haces la consulta de esos tres campos y el la respuesta del ajax le pasas esos valores seleccionando los campos por su id.

Comment: edite mi publicación y cree un código como me indicas con ajax no se si esa es la forma que me sugieres

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veo que la forma de obtener los valores no es la correcta, es decir, `.value=` no es exclusivamente de **Jquery**, y veo que lo estás haciendo con Jquery, intenta obtener el valor con `.val()`. Puede que este código te ayude o te de alguna idea, de esta forma:

```js
$('#no_unidad').on('change', function() {
  $.ajax({     
  url : 'scripts/cargar_valores.php',     
  data : { valor : valor },
  type : 'POST',
  dataType : 'json',
  success : function(json) {
    $("#rendimiento").val(json.rendimiento);
    $("#status").val(json.status);
    $("#fecha").val(json.fecha);
    $("#empresa").val(json.empresa);
    $("#departamento").val(json.departamento);
  },
    error : function(xhr, status) {
    alert('Disculpe, existió un problema');
  }
   });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="no_unidad" id="no_unidad" class="form-control">
  <option value="rendimiento">Rendimiento</option>
  <option value="2019-05-10">2019-05-10</option>
  <option value="csn">CSN</option>
</select><br><br>

<input type="text" class="form-control" name="rendimiento" id="rendimiento" placeholder="Rendimiento">

<input type="date" class="form-control" name="fecha" id="fecha">

<select name="empresa" id="empresa" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Seleccione...</option>
  <option value="csn">CSN</option>
  <option value="sea">SEA</option>
  <option value="cta">CTA</option>
</select>
```

Comment: ya lo edite puse val como me indicas pero aun no logro hacer que se me llenen los campos

Comment: Y el select que optienes desde la BD está trayendo los datos correctamente?

Comment: yo digo que si ya que se me llena con los datos de la BD me trae el id y el nombre

Comment: Manda un `console.log(json)` para que veas los datos que traes y si estás accediendo bien a ellos.

Comment: en lugar de traerme los datos me arroja la alerta que puse

Comment: Edité la respuesta, te dejo un código funcional, puede que te ayude. Sólo tienes que colocar en .val() lo que te devuelve el ajax, es decir: .val(json.rendimiento);  "Según fue lo que te entendí"

Comment: en el ejemplo como ejecuto la función si no esta el evento onchange en el select?

Comment: Ya te agrego el `$('#no_unidad').on('change', function() {   });` no necesitas agregar el `onchange=""` en la etiqueta, además de que es una mala práctica agregar en línea las funciones de JS en el HTML.

Comment: aa ok pero si quito el onchange y lo hago como en el ejemplo como ejecuto la función para hacer la petición por ajax

Comment: Lo que dice @VickMuñoz es cierto, no es recomendable usar métodos Js en el HTML, en el ejemplo que te dejé, ya se ejecuta el `onchange` al momento de seleccionar una opción, lo único que debes hacer, es reemplazar los respectivos valores en tu AJAX

Comment: pero si quito el onchange y lo hago como en el ejemplo como ejecuto la función para hacer la petición por ajax

Comment: Voy a editar la respuesta, mostrándote como.

Comment: ok si ya lo intente con tu ejemplo pero me temo que el error lo tengo en mi script donde hago la petición por que sigue sin traerme nada de datos

Comment: Mmm.. Ok, vale, soluciona si quieres primero lo de la petición, y después seguimos mirando.

Comment: ya lo solucione si tenia un error en la consulta de la pagina cargar_valores.php y ya con el código que me proporcionaste funciono muchas gracias !!

Comment: Ok @jasieltorres, me alegra haber podido ayudarte.